Poetry - Install Package on Specific Python Versions
I have a project that can run on python 3.9 and 3.11, but some parts of it only work on python 3.9. This means that there are some dependencies that I want to install only if running on python 3.9 and not on 3.11 .
I have brought here a similar case with typing_extensions and pydantic - the first package has two versions, one for 3.9 and 3.11, and the second has only for 3.9. I expect this to work because on 3.9 all the requirements can be resolved, and on 3.11 pydantic should not be installed at all.
[tool.poetry]
name = "p1"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["me"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
typing-extensions = [
    {version = "~3.7.2", python = "<3.10"},
    {version = "~3.6.2", python = "^3.11"}
]
pydantic = {version = "~1.6.1", python = "<3.10", extras = ["typing_extensions"]}

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"


Unfortunately, when running poetry lock this yields the following error:
Because no versions of pydantic match >1.6.1,<1.6.2 || >1.6.2,<1.7.0
 and pydantic[typing-extensions] (1.6.1) depends on typing-extensions (>=3.7.2), pydantic[typing-extensions] (>=1.6.1,<1.6.2 || >1.6.2,<1.7.0) requires typing-extensions (>=3.7.2).
And because pydantic[typing-extensions] (1.6.2) depends on typing-extensions (>=3.7.2), pydantic[typing-extensions] (>=1.6.1,<1.7.0) requires typing-extensions (>=3.7.2).
So, because p1 depends on both typing-extensions (>=3.6.2,<3.7.0) and pydantic[typing-extensions] (~1.6.1), version solving failed.

I will be glad to know if I misread the official documentation or is this a bug in poetry.
Thanks a lot!
